# sort table from low to high using .each

Tags: jquery

```js
var tr;
var data = [2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979];


$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  tr = $('<tr class="row" />');
  if () { //what condition to compare if current value is less than current to append lower value
    tr.append('<td>' + value + '</td>');
  }
  $('#table').append(tr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table'>
</table>
```

I want to sort my tables. I cant get the current value and previous to compare.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. If you want a table with sorted data, sort the data, then make the table - much easier.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/34656145/4255447

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an array of integer values, so you can simply call `sort()` on that array before looping through to create the table. There's no need for complex order-checking logic here. Try this:

```js
var tr = '';
var data = [2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979];

$.each(data.sort(), function(index, value) { // note the use of `sort() here
  tr += '<tr class="row"><td>' + value + '</td></tr>';
})
$('#table').append(tr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table'></table>
```

If you want the years in descending order, use `data.sort().reverse()`

Comment: If you want to sort on any of the object `key` then i have created function http://stackoverflow.com/a/34656145/4255447

Comment: @ParthTrivedi there's no keys here, this is an array of integer values, not objects.

Comment: i didnt know that one exist happy coding mate :) ty

Comment: i need 3 more minutes